# How to determine when new finger print is registered or old is deleted in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

I tried to use  biometricManager but there is no such error like new FingerPrint is added or old is deleted. how to handle it ?

```
fun checkBiometricFeatureState(biometricManager: BiometricManager) : Int? {
         when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
             BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> return BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE
             BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> return BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE
             BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> return BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED
             BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_SECURITY_UPDATE_REQUIRED -> return BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_SECURITY_UPDATE_REQUIRED
             BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> return BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS
         }
         return  null
     }
```

Comment: Neither adding nor deleting a fingerprint is an error. Also, the details of how many fingerprints are registered is internal to the OS and hardware -- that information is not available to apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to disable biometric button on login page after there is new fingerPrint add or old deleted, So how can handle it

Comment: If you are using the `KeyStore`, you can [use `setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean)) when setting up your encryption key. I am uncertain if there is a way to detect enrollments/unenrollments in general.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah Im using KeyStore, but I have no specific clue how it works :D , just general, I will try handle it via your suggestion  thanks bro, have a good day ^^